# Laravel Forge Database not Connecting with Sequel Pro

Tags: wordpress, laravel, database-connection, digital-ocean, sequelpro

When I connect to my Laravel Forge server via Sequel Pro, it just sits there saying

***Connecting...***

But, it never does. I've even tested the connection, before connecting and it succeeds.

Keep in mind, I have installed WordPress via Forge, and can view the database when I log into the Digital Ocean server with no problems.

I've done this several times with multiple server spin ups with the same results.

Any ideas as to what could be wrong? I mean, it's all pretty straight forward, and I have other Forge installations that I'm able to connect with via Sequel Pro. Super weird!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are the wordpress database and laravel database in the same host? are they use same ip and port?

Comment: It's simply a WordPress site and database. Nothing to do with Laravel except that it's on Forge.